# TypeError:productlist.products.push is not a function

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is code for Factories

```
        LifeStyleFactoryMOdule.factory("PurchaseFactory",function(){

var productlist={products:[]};

return{
    getpurchaseCart:function(){
        return productlist;
    },
    addPurchaseCart:function(products){

    productlist.products.push(products);

},
    deletePurchase:function(idx){
        productlist.products.splice(idx,1)
    }

}
})
```

Services

```
LifeStyleServiceModule.service("PurchaseService",function(PurchaseFactory){

this.getAllPurchase=function(){
    return PurchaseFactory.getpurchaseCart();
}
this.addPurchase=function(products)
{
    PurchaseFactory.addPurchaseCart(products);
}
 this.deletePurchase=function(idx,id)
{
    PurchaseFactory.deletePurchase(idx,id);
}

})
```

Controllers having function

```
 LifeStyleController.controller("PurchaseController",function($scopePurchaseService){   
$scope.savepurchase=function(products){

    if($scope.products._id==undefined){       

        $scope.products=angular.extend($scope.products,$scope.sizes)
         PurchaseService.addPurchase($scope.products);
       $scope.products={};
  $scope.sizes={size:[]}

}
}
```

In HTML i having a button and all the data i am sending.
First Time I push the data is is done successfully, but for second time its showing me error as productlist.products.push is not a function

Knowing answer will be great help

Comment: Not clear what you are asking to do... What do you mean with "using $resource only with html"?

Comment: I mean to ask is, i want to access the products from the JSON array which i will select dynamically from veg,nonveg,rice.

Comment: A bit of your code (besides the JSON response) could be usefull...

Comment: I think you are sending an empty object, which is should be an array. So check once the code where you are doing it.

Comment: Thanks @ANK, I got it